# Область видимости итератора в for + if Python

Tags: python, if, for, область-видимости

Цикл for перебирает элементы списка "a" и сравнивает 1 элемент и следующий за ним другой элемент

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for (i, j) in (zip(range(len(a)), range(1, len(a)+1))):
    if int(a[i]) == int(a[j]):
        print(a[i])
        i += 2
        j += 2
```

В результате выводятся последние две 4, а нужно чтобы код выполнил сравнения:

```
...
3≠4
4=4
4≠5
...
```

Как пропустить среднюю 4 в списке "а"? Попробовал их вручную увеличивать (последние две строки кода), но это не дает сделать область видимости (если я правильно понял).

На данном этапе результат выполнения кода: 1 4 4
А я пытаюсь получит: 1 4

P.s. этот код будет в отдельной функции и массив у него будет и нескольких тысяч значений.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте цикл `while` для ручного управления индексом. Цикл `for` на каждой итерации обновляет свои переменные вне зависимости от того, что в них было записано вами в теле цикла.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
i = 0
while i < len(a)-1:
    if a[i] == a[i+1]:
        print(a[i], "=", a[i+1])
        i += 1
    else:
        print(a[i], "≠", a[i+1])
    i += 1
```

```
1 = 1
2 ≠ 3
3 ≠ 4
4 = 4
4 ≠ 5
5 ≠ 6
6 ≠ 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Попытка присвоить переменным i j новые значения с целью "перепрыгнуть" некоторые элементы, ничего не даст, так как при начале цикла им присваивается новое значение. Однако до конца итерации их можно менять как угодно.
Здесь нужен подход основаный на continue,- пропуске текущей итерации. В твоём случае этого можно достичь применив условие `if a[i]==4 or a[j]==4: continue;` Так же может быть полезным введение переменной, сигнализирующей о том, что итерацию необходимо прервать:

```
cont=False
for (i, j) in (zip(range(len(a)), range(1, len(a)+1))):
    if int(a[i]) == int(a[j]):
        cont=True
    else:
        cont=False
    if cont:
        continue
    #основные действия цикла
```

Comment: Результат такой же, '1 4 4'.  И почему в первый if сразу не вписать continue?

Comment: Введение дополнительной переменной будет полезно при более сложных случаях. Вероятно потому что, принт стоит перед continue